# Combining two different API requests in Elm

Tags: elm

I have a client which depends on a third party API, and I need to combine two calls into one record (or be able to display content from both calls in one view).

I have no experience with Elm, but understand there is a concept of Task which may be helpful. Collecting data to two different models is also something I have considered, but it seems to give me some problems displaying the data.

Here are the resources I want to combine

```
data1 = [{a, b, c1:{x1,y1}, c2:{x2,y2}}, ...]
data2 = [{x1, y1, z1, q1}, {x2, y2, z2, q2}, ...]
```

I want to display data1 with the enhanced c variable from data2.

Expected result

```
data = [{a, b, c1:{x1,y1,z1,q1}, c2:{x2,y2,z2,q2}, ...]
```

Is combining the resources on a local server and then fetch the data as one model the easiest choice?

Comment: Your questions has quite a lot of options you seem to have considered, but I have problem grasping what is the actual problem you are trying to solve. Thus only concentrating on symptoms instead of the source might give you poor advice. That being said, you could combine the two lists with [`List.map2` function](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#map2). Type system might give you some head aches though.

Comment: I want to merge records from data2 into the c variable of data1. Each record of data2 have a unique id, which have to match the same id of c. Its not a straight forward map task, but maybe it is possible? My model consists of Loading, Failure, and Success (List data1 records). Success is now tied up to viewing data1, and I am not sure how to capture data2. Creating another model would require a view function, and I do not want that. Can I fetch data to some sort of state, except Model, and then use it in the view function with data1?

Comment: IMO your question still has too many open aspects and it is hard to understand what are the actual issues you are facing. I'd suggest that you modify your question in order to either 1) generalize it, i.e. ask general advice on how to solve a specific design issue in Elm, or 2) specialize on *single* issue you'd like to solve. Examples of case 2) would be how to combine the lists, how to use "another model" or how to use states to control model etc.

Comment: Might be beyond the scope of your question, but I would consider using GraphQL to combine the APIs (e.g. with [Hasura](https://blog.hasura.io/remote-joins-a-graphql-api-to-join-database-and-other-data-sources/)). As a bonus you can then use [`elm-graphql`](https://github.com/dillonkearns/elm-graphql).